# VB.NET Update a new GUID on a Log-In Form

Tags: sql, vb.net, cookies, guid

Well I have a login form, and i need to connect to my database and interate with the collumns.

So, my table is tb_Users and I have user_id, descrit(user), userkey for guid and password.

Now, To create a new Guid i know i need to use:

```vb
Dim Guid As String 

Guid = System.Guid.NewGuid.ToString()
```

and i do this: (I have a class for SQL Connection to my database)

```vb
Dim SQL As New CDSI.Servers


Protected Sub Btn_Submit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btn_Submit.Click
    Dim Cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim Rs As SqlDataReader
    Dim User As New CDSI_UserInfo
    If SQL.Connect() Then
        Cmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT descrit, password, user_id, user_key, last_logon FROM tbUsers WHERE descrit='" & Me.FXdescrit.Text & "' AND password='" & Me.FXpassword.Text & "'", CDSI.SQLServer)
        Rs = Cmd.ExecuteReader()
        If Rs.HasRows Then
            If Rs.Read = True Then
                If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Rs.Item("descrit")) Or String.IsNullOrEmpty(Rs.Item("password")) Then

                    '1º Create Guid
                    Dim Guid As String
                    Guid = System.Guid.NewGuid.ToString()

                    '2º Registry Guid on tbUsers (UPDATE on SQL)
                    Cmd = New SqlCommand("UPDATE tbUsers SET user_key='" & Rs.Item(Guid.ToString) & "' WHERE descrit='" & Rs.Item("descrit") & "'")

                    '3º Save Guid on Cookie

                End If
            Else
                Me.FXerro.Text = "Conexão deu erro"
            End If
        Else
            Me.FXerro.Text = "Nome ou Password Não defenidos. Por favor tente novamente."
        End If
        Rs.Close()
    End If
    SQL.Disconnet()
End Sub
```

Comment: please sepcify what you need help with, and what trouble you are having.

Comment: Sorry for my bad english, i need help to register my new Guid for my sql Collumn "user_key" . now i do another thing:

Cmd = New SqlCommand("UPDATE tbUsers SET user_key='" & Rs.Item(Guid.ToString) & "' WHERE descrit='" & Rs.Item("descrit") & "'")

Comment: Please edit your original post to add code, so that it can be inside a code block. What is the column type of your guid?

Comment: Cant edit, lol, but user_id = int; descrit = nvarchar(50) and user_key=nvarchar(50)

Comment: We need to know what issue you are having. Cant register isn't enough info. As an aside, I would suggest using a paramaratized query.

Comment: I can't put my created GUI on my collumn "user_key" ..

Comment: Why not? I am asking you to share the error message, which will be part of the learning process.I have a sneaking suspicion what your problem may be, but I'd like to help you arrive at the same conclusion because that will help you learn to troubleshoot your code. So, pass along the error. Is the column simply blank - I think not. I bet you have an error.

Comment: Thanks to who have edited my Question :) . Now, @Levi my collumn have 0, like my Gui its: BA902083-5B70-4263-A35B-E96CC91E6C86, and this is the error that appears. I think its anything about the size, but i put in my "user_key" collumn, varchar(50) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change
    user_key='" & Rs.Item(Guid.ToString) & "' 
to

```
user_key='" Guid & "'
```

it looks like you are trying to set you column user_key with a recordset item that you are not grabbing from the select statement. You just want to pass in the string Guid, which is a poorly conceived name, by the way.

Comment: Well, i did it and you're right! The SqlCommand when open, must be executed and closed. This was my problem and that is now resolved.